# R-squared vs. t-test confusion

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, r-squared

I am using regression tree for this educational exercise. I have 500 observation points of independent variables $X$ and dependent variable $Y$. I use 400 points to generate my model and keep 100 points for out of sample (OOS) testing.

I then, use the model to predict new Y (Y_predicted) for OOS data. I then, obtain R-squared using original Y from OOS data and Y_predicted. I also perform a t-test on (Y - Y_predicted). The R-squared comes out to be negative and t-test fails to reject null at 5%. The null being the mean difference of Y and Y_predicted is zero.

I am confused about how to interpret this result. R-squared is saying my model is basically bogus but t-test is saying that since mean difference of Y and Y_predicted is 0 at 5% level, so the model is appropriate.

R-squared is calculated on OOS original Y and predicted Y using model.
t-test was run on OOS (Y - Y_predicted)

Comment: The t-test is failing to reject the null hypothesis that your model is unbiased.  This is not the same as saying your model is appropriate, after all, the sample mean of the $y_i$ is unbiased (no need to run a t-test to test that hypothesis!) and is a different model, almost certainly, than your regression tree ended up with. The negative $R^2$ means that your model's predictive variance is less than that of the sample mean of... what?  The OOS data or the 400 in-sample data points?

Comment: My model predicted some Y and for each predicted Y there was an original given Y. If the difference of these is statistically 0, then my model must have done a good job ? What is wrong in the logic. Sorry my statistics is not so strong so might be missing on fundamentals.

Comment: "*If the difference of these is statistically 0, then my model must have done a good job*" -- @jbowman has already explained why this is not necessarily the case. Clearly, it doesn't follow.

Comment: Even if your average error is zero, it doesn't mean your model does a good job. Consider a "model" of a data series with 20 data points.  My prediction for the first 19 data points is... 100 billion!  And the prediction for the 20th data point is whatever number will make the average error = 0.  A terrible model, one might suspect, but it will always pass a t-test on whether the mean difference of $Y$ and $Y_{pred}$ is zero.

Comment: So, how does one make ttest robust and more reliable ? The example you gave basically makes me think that all ttests that I have done so far might be fake.

Comment: It's not a question of the robustness or reliability of the t-test. That's not remotely the issue here. It's simply answering a *different* question to the one you would like it to answer. If you use a t-test in the way you suggest, you're misusing it (in that you're using it to try to answer a different question to the one it *does* answer), and that's *not the fault of the t-test*. It's like asking what's wrong with a perfectly good hammer *when it's not doing a great job of hammering in screws*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers of jbowman and Glen_b already cover the whole story.

Conclusion from t-test: Your tree provides predictions that are not systematically biased. This is nice to have but not sufficient to make your tree a good model (see jbowman's example). A t-test is about averages, not about individual values.

Conclusion from negative R-squared: Predictions from the tree are typically worse than simply using the average response as prediction. Thus, the tree is a very bad predictor.